# mvc3 - facebook like showing index not website name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-like

I am using asp.net mvc3 framework and have uploaded my site to server. But on clicking facebook like button, it shows up on facebook as Index instead of site name. How can i change that? Also is there a way to add logo in front of the name also?
Here is my fb code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com/" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="light" data-font="arial"></div>
```

Facebook script:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=*********";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: Please add more tags for more exposure to your question. Add the following tags: facebook and facebook-javascript-sdk

Comment: @BrendanVogt - Hi i added all the FB used code. Thanks!

Comment: I meant tags, not code. Tags are those blue "buttons" beneath your question. More tags means more people see your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Open Graph tags on the site or at the very least you need to give your home page a proper page title. Add OG tags to whatever view that represents the "liked" URL.

Facebook makes an http request to the url to get some meta data, then they look for Open Graph tags located in page header, if those are not found it will fall back to page title and meta description attribute. Look at [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) in Open Graph Tags section. Here is a sample of an open graph tag implementation in html:

```
<head>
<title>My Super site</title>
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/my_super_image.jpg">
<meta property="og:title" content="My super site">
</head>
```

Also, the site **MUST BE LIVE IN PRODUCTION**, so Facebook can access the page.